# ACF field on Product Attribute show on single product page

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, advanced-custom-fields

I'm trying to add a logo to a Woocommerce product attribute (Brand Logo) and then display that brand logo on the Single Product page for each product tagged with that attribute.

I've tried the way I thought it would work however looks far too simple and it returns null.

```
<?php

function brandLogo(){
    
    global $product;
    
    ?><p><?php the_field('brand_logo'); ?></p><?php
    
}

add_shortcode('brandLogo', 'brandLogo');
?>
```

I've got the ACF field to return URL of the image and have also tried using get_field as well as the_field.

My php knowledge is quite limited so I can't quite figure out how to get this one sorted.

Cheers.

Comment: Both `the_field` and `get_field` rely on the global post ID, which is probably not set, or not set to the right post here. Try and get the ID from the $product variable, and explicitly pass that as second parameter.

Answer (score 1):

I have changed the code and learned that it is important to use 'pa_' for product attribute names. So 'pa_yourattribute'. Here is the working code:

```
<?php

function brandLogo(){
    
    global $product;
    
    $terms = get_the_terms($post->ID , 'pa_brand');
    
    if($terms){
        foreach ($terms as $term){
            
                ?><img src="<?php the_field('brand_logo', 'pa_brand' . '_' . $term->term_id) ?>"/><?php
        }
    }
    
}

add_shortcode('brandLogo', 'brandLogo');

?>
```